# Vertical align middle div with center div

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS below :

```css
.lpanel{
 text-align: center;
 height: 50px;
}
.logo{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 25px;
}
.slogan{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="lpanel">
            <div class="logo">LOGO HERE</div>
            <div class="slogan">SLOGAN IS HERE</div>
    </div>
```

I know can using `display:table` for .lpanel and `display:table-cell` for .slogan to vertical middle this slogan div but I can't do this because when I add display:table for .lpanel then 2 class .logo and .slogan not align center.

You can see picture :
[image]

How to fix this ?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: what you want to do??

Comment: I was add picture. You can see

Comment: so you want the slogan to align in center

Comment: Logo and slogan to align center

Comment: its in center only?? run your snippet

Comment: Yes this code above can align center to class logo and slogan but not vertical align middle class Slogan. When I vertical align middle class Slogan it not center align anymore

Comment: @NathanTuggy not duplicate :)

Comment: @Ivan is there any problem in your question i don't  thing there is problem in your question

Comment: That may be the case, but frankly it's not clear why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Ivan explain exactly what your problem is

Comment: perhaps it is a browser issue?

Comment: @Ivan answered solved your question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add vertical align to both the elements

```css
.lpanel {
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slogan {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="lpanel">
  <div class="logo">LOGO HERE</div>
  <div class="slogan">SLOGAN IS HERE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example..

```css
.lpanel {
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}
.lpanel div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.slogan {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lpanel">
  <div class="logo">LOGO HERE</div>
  <div class="slogan">SLOGAN IS HERE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.lpanel{
            margin-top:50px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 50px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 50px;
            
        }
        .logo{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 100px;
        }
        .slogan{
            display: inline-block;
            float: top;
        }
```

```html
     <div class="lpanel">
            <div class="logo">LOGO HERE</div>
            <div class="slogan">SLOGAN IS HERE</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It not 'vertical-align: middle;' .You can add bigger font size to see this.